# Should all the form's submit work after a valid one submit with CSRF?

Tags: spring, forms, csrf

I am using CSRF with spring.

When I enabled this, cant submit any form (makes sence since I need the token for every post).

The problem is this:

After I submit a form with a valid token (in my case , the login). all other submit forms keep working... as far as I understand, should not work.

Any idea why is this?

I am using spring 3.2 and security 3.2.5

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you are using JSP and are using the Spring form tags it works as designed.

The token is automatically added to the form through the use of a [`RequestDataValueProcessor`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/support/RequestDataValueProcessor.html.). When using the Spring Security namespace or annotation based configuration support the [`CsrfRequestDataValueProcessor`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/master/web/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/web/servlet/support/csrf/CsrfRequestDataValueProcessor.java) is automatically configured and added to the configuration.

This is also mentioned in the Spring Security [reference guide](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/csrf.html#csrf-include-csrf-token).

> If you are using Spring MVC `<form:form>` tag or Thymeleaf 2.1+ and are using `@EnableWebSecurity`, the `CsrfToken` is automatically included for you (using the `CsrfRequestDataValueProcessor`).

Comment: Hi, I know, and it works like that, but the token is the same all time.. I was wondering how could I ask for a new one for each post submit

Comment: By implementing a different csfr approach and wire that up. The default uses the same token over and over.